# How to get a correlation coefficient table of a data set

Tags: r, list, dataframe, correlation, r-corrplot

My sample data is below;

It has 40 rows and 26 columns including headers

```
Constituency: 01 | HP Deprivation Score | Total Population 2011| 5?year Population Change| Age Dependency Rate| Proportion of Lone Parents | |
Carlow-Kilkenny -1.70   145,659 8.9 34.1    19.0
Cavan-Monaghan  -3.90   120,483 11.9    35.2    17.5
Clare   -0.40   111,336 5.5 34.7    17.5
Cork East   0.50    114,365 14.2    34.7    18.6
Cork North-Central  -0.40   117,131 3.2 30.6    26.1
Cork North-West 2.10    86,593  9.7 34.2    15.8
Cork South-Central  4.90    117,991 5.6 31.2    20.0
Cork South-West 2.00    82,952  7.8 36.0    15.4
Donegal -6.30   152,358 9.7 36.3    23.0
```

I try to get a correlation coefficient table/matrix for each column and want to keep the constituency names. Here is the code I've tried based on other answers;

```
library(corrplot)
election2016[is.na(election2016)] = 0

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(election2016), nrow=39, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
M <- cor(df)
corrplot(M, method="circle")
```

The table I got is not accurate as it contains different numbers in the data frame.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of `dput(yourData)` into your question to make it reproducible.

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, you have to just pass the numeric columns to the `cor` function. Limiting the data to numeric columns only by using `cor(df[,2:6])` will yield a correlation table for input to `corrplot`.